# Logback rolls over once and stops rollover (windows with tomcat)

Tags: windows, tomcat, logback

I have a tomcat application on windows server, and I configured the application logs with Logback - see logback.xml below.
The problem I have is that the logs rollover once or twice, and then the original logs keeps growing.

Here is my logback.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="${catalina.home}/../../Logs/folder/Tomcat"/>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}/someName.log</file>
        <encoder> <!-- class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder" -->
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread]: %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${HOME_LOG}/archived/someName.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>20KB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>false</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="eventReportsAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!--file>${HOME_LOG}/eventsReport.log</file-->
        <encoder> <!-- class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder" -->
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread]: %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${HOME_LOG}/archived/eventsReport.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>false</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mchange">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="eventReportsAppender"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I think the problem is that the application service is locking the log file and it cannot be renamed for rollover.
    When I remove the file tag, the logs are being rolled over, but the naming contains an index which I want to avoid.